# Hibernate collection mapping: map<String, Entity2> property in Entity1

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, many-to-one

I am trying to map the following entities with (legacy) DB tables and have trouble with mapping a map:

```
public class Configuration {

    private Long configurationId;
    private String code;
    private Long index;

    private Map<String, ConfigurationParam> configurationParams;
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class ConfigurationParam {

    private Long configurationId; // foreign key
    private String code;
    private String value;
    ...
}
```

As you can see, a *configuration* object holds a map of *configurationParam* objects. The key of the map is the code property of *ConfigurationParam* . Please note that the properties *code* of each entities are not related to each other (legacy schema :( )

The hibernate mapping looks like this:

```
<class name="Configuration" table="CONFIGURATION" dynamic-update="true">
    <id name="configurationId" column="CONFIGURATIONID">
      <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="configurationSetId" column="CONFIGURATIONSETID" /> 
    <property name="code" column="CODE" /> 
    <property name="index" column="INDX" /> 

    <map name="configurationParams" lazy="true" table="CONFIGURATIONPARAM"  fetch="select"  
        batch-sie="10">
        <key column="CONFIGURATIONID" />
        <map-key type="string" column="CODE"/>
        <element type="ConfigurationParam"></element>
    </map>
  </class>
```

and

```
<class name="ConfigurationParam" table="CONFIGURATIONPARAM" dynamic-update="true">
    <composite-id class="ConfigurationParamId" mapped="true">
        <key-property name="configurationId"/>
        <key-property name="code"/>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="configurationId" column="CONFIGURATIONID" /> 
    <property name="code" column="CODE" /> 
    <property name="value" column="VALUE" />
</class>
```

However, the params are not loaded in the desired way, also not if I turn on eager fetching and also not if I try to fetch Configurations with a named query and *join fetch configurationParams*.

Why is this the case? And how to map the association correctly?

I already had some ideas what the problem could be this seems not to be the problem (at least alone):

1. both entities have a property named *code* , probably the wrong one is used as *map-key* by Hibernate?
   (It should of course use the *code* property of the ConfigurationParam entity.)
2. ConfigurationParam.code is not unique. As you see, the primary key of ConfigurationParam is a composite.
   However, since it is a map maintained by Configuration whose primary key is the second part of this composite, I think this should be OK. Hibernate did not complain anyway.
3. ConfigurationParam.code is already mapped as property in the entity itself. Probably, then you cannot use it as map key anymore? However, also this Hibernate would tell me, I guess?

I tried to find answers in the Hibernate documentation (you know cats and such things) and read a lot of other questions here but did not find an answer to this particular issue

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it to work after all. The mapping of the map owning entity has to be like this:

```
<map name="configurationParams">
    <key column="CONFIGURATIONID" />
    <map-key type="string" column="CODE"/>
    <one-to-many class="ConfigurationParam" />
</map>
```

It seems that the *element* tag is used for basic type mappings (e.g. for Map). If you want to have mapped entities as map values, you need a one-to-many tag.

The hibernate documentation states: "*For collections of a basic or embeddable type use @ElementCollection*" (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html)  .

Although it is not explained in detail and not for xml mappings, I read it like this after having solved my issue.